# HCatalog 1.2 createRecordReader PartInfo's TableInfo is null

Tags: hive, hcatalog

When I updated my project from hive 0.13 to hive 1.2 I created a `HCatMutilTableInputFormat` for input multi-table to `MapReduce` by `HCatlog`. In hive 0.13 the method `createRecordReader` of `inputFormat` can get the `TableInfo` from the `inputSplit`. But the version 1.2 can't.

Below is the error message I get -

The  method `createRecordReader` of Hcatalog 1.2 `HCatBaseInputFormat` and the `partitionInfo.getTableInfo()` is null.

Can anyone tell me why? Can I get the `tableInfo` from the `InputSplit`? How can I get it ?

Here is my code -

```
HCatSplit hcatSplit = InternalUtil.castToHCatSplit(split);
    PartInfo partitionInfo = hcatSplit.getPartitionInfo();
    // Ensure PartInfo's TableInfo is initialized.
    if (partitionInfo.getTableInfo() == null) {
        partitionInfo
                .setTableInfo(((InputJobInfo) HCatUtil.deserialize(taskContext.getConfiguration().get(HCatConstants.HCAT_KEY_JOB_INFO))).getTableInfo());
    }
    JobContext jobContext = taskContext;
    Configuration conf = jobContext.getConfiguration();
```